# Debugging ADFS 2.0 errors

Tags: wif, .net-4.5, adfs, ws-trust

I am trying to get a SAML 2.0 token from an ADFS 2.0 ws-trust service using C#. The popular sample is this one  http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/16/wcf-and-identity-in-net-4-5-external-authentication-with-ws-trust/.  However, this sample uses a UserNameWSTrustBinding which, according to this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157091.aspx, did not make the jump to the System.IdentityModel namespace for 4.5.

I have been experimenting with this sample and some variants that I have found, but so far, the only results that I can get are a variety of error messages.  I am wondering if there is any good way to debug the latest one, "The request for security token has invalid or malformed elements.".  I turned on WCF logging on and determined that this message is being returned as a fault by the ADFS service.

Reviewing the AD FS 2.0/Admin events on the ADFS server, there is no indication of an error.  Several posts indicate that this is common in an ADFS farm environment, but mine is a simple single server configuration.

Does anyone have a good way to diagnose this?  Or, is there a good sample that comes with any configuration requirements on the ADFS server side?

Answer (score 1):

This link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Geneva/thread/33fc091b-505c-481c-a61c-a8541a5ccf23 shows how to enable WCF and WIF tracing for the server side of ADFS 2.0.  Modify the config file at C:\Program Files\Active Directory Federation Services 2.0\Microsoft.IdentityServer.Servicehost.exe.config.  (Change the three switchValue settings to Verbose and modify the trace listeners.) While following the instructions, make sure to change the types on the listeners.  Something like

```
<add name="ADFSWifListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logs\adfs1.svclog" />
```

I also had to grant "Everyone" full access to the C:\Logs folder, you can refine those permissions with auditing if you like.  Once the .svclog files have been created, they can be viewed with SvcTraceViewer.exe in %ProgramFiles%/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v8.0A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools (or any other SDK version probably).

NOTE: Microsoft will not support the notion of logging trace data directly to a file, so you will want to turn this off or configure according to this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-troubleshooting-configuring-computers(WS.10).aspx for a production deployment.